# Why should $z = \alpha x+ (1 - \alpha)y$ also be a solution of the given equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> In order for $A−1$ to exist, $Ax = b$ must have exactly one solution for
>   every value of $b$. However, it is also possible for the system of
>   equations to have no solutions or infinitely many solutions for some
>   values of $b$. It is not possible to have more than one but less than
>   infinitely many solutions for a particular $b$; if both $x$ and $y$ are
>   solutions then $z = αx + (1 − α)y$ is also a solution for any
>   real $α$.

I'm relatively new to Linear Algebra so I haven't been able to understand as to why $z = αx + (1 − α)y$ must also be a solution if there exists multiple solutions.

Comment: To complete the claim that one obtains infinitely many solutions this way, there still remains to show that different $\alpha$ lead to different $z$ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}Az&=A(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\\[0.2cm]&=A(\alpha x)+A\left((1-\alpha)y\right)\\[0.2cm]&=\alpha \cdot Ax+(1-\alpha)\cdot Ay=\alpha\cdot b+(1-\alpha)\cdot b=b\end{align*}